# What server-side architectures could provide high availability and avoid race conditions?

Tags: state, distributed-computing, race-condition, distributed-system, eventual-consistency

I have the following (flawed) distributed architecture, which has race conditions. I know some of you probably have solutions to this classic "distributed state propagation problem" - and I would love to hear them. If you bear with me, here's the architecture:

Let's say you have two golang app servers, S1 and S2.

There's also two Cassandra database nodes, DB1 and DB2.

S1 and S2 are each connected to both DB1 and DB2.

A user does two things at about the same time, from two browsers:

1. He opens a client browser, C1, that will connect to S1 via websockets and make requests to get state from either DB1 or DB2. Message M1 contains the state and is sent from S1 to C1.
2. He opens client browser, C2, that will connect to S2 to toggle some state. S2 will update that state in either DB1 or DB2. DB1 and DB2 will then sync with each other. S2 also needs to tell C1 about the new state, and sends this state-update-message using NSQ (or your favorite message queue) to S1, who then sends message M2 with the state change to C1.

Now, there are hairy race conditions between (1) and (2). On C1, what arrives first, M1 or M2? M1 might include the state update contained in M2, or not, depending on the timing of the Cassandra propagation relative to C1's request.

I realize that idempotent messages or CRDTs would solve this for some use cases, but not all -- particularly for non-monotonic state changes like a boolean toggle state.

I realize that OST (operational state transfer) might also solve this, but I don't know of any good off-the-shelf solutions. I've built an OST system previously and it's a major PITA.

Certainly, one could have a more consistent kind of database which makes this more tractable, but I need high availability with partition tolerance and that means dealing with eventual consistency.

It might solve this to have database hooks/callbacks where an app server can listen for changes to certain state, and be notified when the state propagation reaches that db node. I know these kinds of hooks exist in some consistent databases like Rethinkdb, but (to my knowledge) they don't exist in Cassandra or any other highly-available (HA), partition-tolerant (PT) database.

I find myself craving an application-level state abstraction that's: cross-platform; integrates with HA/PT distributed persistent storage; handles the state propagation for me; and makes it easy to trigger behavior when state changes. I don't know of anything like this.

What tools or architectures are you aware of, that would satisfy these constraints:

- no race conditions
- highly-available, partition-tolerant (eventually consistent)
- handles non-monotonic state changes

Answer (score 0):

I think that Cassandra has very peculiar features but can't manage transactions in the way that you need even if you would use a single node.
I don't know why you use Cassandra, maybe you have reason to be stitched to it but for your needs I would use a cluster of SQL db in HA configuration: Oracle or SQL Server already solved these problems. Of course they could be expensive

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of your Cassandra servers e.g. DB1 as a lock server. This will guarantee atomicity of all of your operations, so in your case operations will not interfere each other.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, though doesn't that create a single point of failure?

Comment: Not really. If the lock server is down then you're just doing what you're currently doing. I mean if you're lucky and the lock server is up then you have consistency. If you're unlucky and it is down then you don't. But isn't it better than not to have consistency all the times?

Comment: "Unreliable locking" -- that's interesting. lock/unlock when you can (most of the time), but don't let that stop an operation.

Comment: Exactly. But you will be able to do everything smoother, if you avoid distributed locking and distributed transactions. Try to have at one server all the data that you need in one transaction. Is that possible in your case?